# Capture a video thumbnail in Flex/Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, video, actionscript, air, thumbnails

I am writing an Adobe Air application.  Users will be able to import videos into the application, but to save on memory for certain parts of the application, it is required of me to convert these videos into thumbnail .jpgs first and to only display the thumbnails in a tilelist.  These thumbnails must therefore be generated dynamically during runtime.  So my question is, how can I convert a video into a thumbnail.  So far, I have tried two different methods.  I have used the ImageSnapshot Class which I got to work, but ONLY if I added the video to the display list first which is not an option.  So then I tried to draw the bitmapdata using the BitmapData class and ran into the same problem.  It would only work if I added the video to the display list first.  Does anyone know how I can get the bitmapdata out of a frame of video without adding the video to the screen first?  Here is the code I am using right now, it writes the final .jpg to your desktop as test.jpg and only works with .mp4 videos.  If you take out the line that says this.AddElement(vd), it no longer works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                                     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                                     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

          <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                              import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;
                              import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;

                              import spark.components.VideoDisplay;
                              import spark.primitives.BitmapImage;
                              private const acceptableTypes:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Media", "*.mp4");
                              private var vd:VideoDisplay;

                              protected function importVideo(event:MouseEvent):void
                              {
                                        var file:File = File.userDirectory;
                                        file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, mediaSelectHandler);
                                        file.browseForOpen("Select File To Import", [acceptableTypes]);
                              }

                              private function mediaSelectHandler(event:Event):void {
                                        vd = new VideoDisplay();
                                        vd.autoPlay = false;
                                        vd.horizontalCenter = 0;
                                        vd.verticalCenter = 0;
                                        vd.source = event.currentTarget.nativePath;
                                        this.addElement(vd);
                              }

                              private function getSnapShot(event:MouseEvent):void{
                                        var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(vd.width, vd.height);
                                        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
                                        bd.draw(vd, matrix);

                                        //save to hard drive
                                        var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
                                        var imgfile:File = file.resolvePath("test.jpg");
                                        var jpegEncoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(90);
                                        var jpegStream:ByteArray = jpegEncoder.encode(bd);
                                        var filestream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                                        filestream.open(imgfile, FileMode.WRITE);
                                        filestream.writeBytes(jpegStream, 0, jpegStream.length);
                                        filestream.close();
                              }
                    ]]>
          </fx:Script>

          <fx:Declarations>
                    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
          </fx:Declarations>
          <s:HGroup width="500" height="40" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="50">
                    <s:Button width="100" height="28" label="IMPORT" click="importVideo(event)"/>
                    <s:Button width="100" height="28" label="SNAPSHOT" click="getSnapShot(event)"/>
          </s:HGroup>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Please don't write your question title in all-capitals.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use ffmpeg utility for that and solution could be taken to next level. For e.g. you upload a 10 minute video. You can take 10 snapshots starting from 1st minute and at an interval of 1 minute duration. This will give you a series of snapshot of video. And you can implement a component as a timeline and on roll over show the related snapshot. You might have seen this in video websites.